# Is a string a valid timezone in .Net

Tags: c#, timezone

I receive a string as a json parameter and it's supposed to be a timezone ID. I want to check for that.

This is what I have:

```
TheTimezoneID = TheTimezoneID.Trim();
var AllTimezones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();

if (TheTimezoneID "is a valid .net timezone" == true) {}
```

What's the linq expression that'll test if `TheTimezoneID` is in `AllTimezones`? I tried using `.Any` but it's not working.

Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you want to do - find if a single string represents a valid timezone, or if a bunch of strings all represent valid timezones.  If you want to test if a whole bunch of timezone IDs are *all* valid, you need .All rather than .Any.

Comment: @AdamMihalcin: Just need to check one string at a time. The user is choosing a timezone from a drop-down on a page: I populate the drop-down with .net's values but I'm still check on the way back.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're going to do this in various situations you should probably use:

```
private static readonly HashSet<string> AllTimeZoneIds = 
    new HashSet<string>(TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()
                                    .Select(tz => tz.Id));
```

Then you can just use:

```
if (AllTimeZoneIds.Contains(timeZoneId))
```

There's no need to use LINQ to iterate over the whole time zone list on each time when a hash set can just perform an O(1) lookup.

If you're just curious about using `Any`, it would be:

```
if (AllTimeZoneIds.Select(tz => tz.Id).Contains(timeZoneid))
```

or

```
if (AllTimeZoneIds.Any(tz => tz.Id == timeZoneid))
```

Note that "time zone ID" is a pretty woolly concept. This will check if it's a valid *.NET* time zone ID. If you're actually getting time zones like "Europe/London", that's a different matter.

Comment: Just curious, what kind of construct is private static readonly HashSet<string>? Is it like a dictionary?

Comment: @frenchie: It's like a dictionary with only keys. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx